# Enabling Activity Logs Diagnostic Settings using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

Currently there exists a module to create a Log Diagnostic Setting for Azure Resources linked [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting). Using the portal I am able to generate a log diagnostic setting for activity logs as well as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log). I was trying to enable activity logs diagnostic settings and send logs to a Storage account and only came across this [module](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_log_profile).

However it seems that it is not possible to use this module to send Activity logs to a Log analytics workspace. It also does not support the Log categories which are mentioned in the portal (i.e `Administrative`,`Security`, `ServiceHealth` etc) and only provides `Action`,`Delete` and `Write`. This leads me to believe that they are not intended to be used for the same purpose. The first module requires a `target_resource_id` and since Activity logs exist in the subscription level no such id exists.

As such is it possible to use the first mentioned module, or an entirely different module to enable diagnostic settings? Any help regarding the matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can configure this by specifying the subscription id as the target_resource_id within a azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting resource.

Example:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
    name                           = "example"
    target_resource_id             = "/subscriptions/85306735-db49-41be-b899-b0fc48095b01"

    eventhub_name = azurerm_eventhub.diagnostics.name
    eventhub_authorization_rule_id = azurerm_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule.diagnostics.id

    log {
        category = "Administrative"

        retention_policy {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the attribute "log_analytics_workspace_id"

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
name                           = "example"
target_resource_id             = "/subscriptions/xxxx"

log_analytics_workspace_id     = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id
log_analytics_destination_type = "Dedicated" # or null see [documentation][1]

log {
    category = "Administrative"

    retention_policy {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the best way I found is first query for all categories, then enabled them all.

```
// enable all diagnostic settings for a resource
data "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories" "logs" {
  resource_id = var.target_resource_id
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "monitor-diagnostic-settings" {
  name                       = "diag-setting"
  target_resource_id         = var.target_resource_id
  storage_account_id         = var.storage_account_id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
  dynamic "log" {
    iterator = entry
    for_each = data.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories.logs.log_category_types
    content {
      category = entry.value
      enabled  = true
    }
  }
  dynamic "metric" {
    iterator = entry
    for_each = data.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories.logs.metrics
    content {
      category = entry.value
      enabled  = true
    }
  }
}
```